# react-virtualized grid retrieves image from service but does not render until scroll action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-virtualized

I am building a component that displays data retrieved from a server in a react-virtualized grid. Everything works fine with the exception of one issue: When the component first renders, the images that are retrieved are not displayed. They will, however, become available once a scroll action takes place.

I think it has something to do with the way my Promises work but I can't seem to find a solution.

The image data is successfully retrieved and the state is successfully updated with the data, however it is still not displayed.

The way I understand this to work is that when any cells in the grid are rendered using the "rowRenderer" callback, the "whenSectionRendered" callback should fire causing the following sequence:

1. a call to "loadNewImagesBetweenIndices"
2. a call to "loadHistImage" for each row between the indices provided
3. "loadHistImage" returns a promise from the imageService.retrieveImage         function that receives the base64 image, then places the image data as "image_decision" on my object and calls "updateSpotHistoryData" with the new object.
4. "updateSpotHistoryData" updates the state, which replaces the "spotHistoryData" state with the new data and triggers a re-render.
5. I expect the re-render to make the image available to display when the "HistoryImageButton" is clicked, but it is not displayed until a scroll event occurs. This is my issue.

I have tried the following things:

1. Calling "loadNewImagesBetweenIndices" in "componentDidMount" and/or "componentDidUpdate".
2. Calling "loadHistImage" directly in the "rowRenderer" callback.
3. Forcing a re-render of the object by using setState again.
4. Removing the "clearImagesBetweenIndicesNotInView" call from "whenSectionRendered" function.

```
class HistoryDisplay extends PureComponent{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      width: 1000,
      previousIdxStart: -1,
      previousIdxStop: -1,
      spotHistoryData: ''
    }

    this.cellRenderer = this.cellRenderer.bind(this);
    this.whenSectionRendered = this.whenSectionRendered.bind(this);
    this.loadHistImage = this.loadHistImage.bind(this);
    this.loadHistory = this.loadHistory.bind(this);
    this.removeHistImages = this.removeHistImages.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.resetRowWidthIfRequired();
    this.loadHistory(this.props.spotId);
  } 

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this.resetPrevIdxIfRequired(prevProps);
    if(prevProps.spotId !== this.props.spotId){ 
      this.loadHistory(this.props.spotId);
    }
  }

  ...

  async loadHistImage(imageId) {
    return imageService.retrieveImage(imageId)
      .then(data => {
        const newHistData = this.state.spotHistoryData.map(x => {
          if (x.id_image_decision === imageId){
            x.image_decision = data;
          }
          return x;
        });
        this.updateSpotHistoryData(newHistData);
      });

  }

  updateSpotHistoryData(newHistoryData) {
    this.setState({
      spotHistoryData: newHistoryData
    });
  }

  whenSectionRendered({rowOverscanStartIndex, rowOverscanStopIndex}) {
    const { previousIdxStart, previousIdxStop } = this.state;
    this.loadNewImagesBetweenIndices(
      this.state.spotHistoryData, 
      rowOverscanStartIndex, 
      rowOverscanStopIndex);
    this.clearImagesBetweenIndicesNotInView(
      rowOverscanStartIndex,
      rowOverscanStopIndex,
      previousIdxStart, 
      previousIdxStop);
  }

  loadNewImagesBetweenIndices(array, startIdx, stopIdx) {
    for(let rowIndex=startIdx; rowIndex<stopIdx; rowIndex++) {
      this.loadHistImage(array[rowIndex].id_image_decision)
    }
    this.setState({
      previousIdxStart: startIdx,
      previousIdxStop: stopIdx
    });
  }

  cellRenderer({columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style}) {
    const { spotHistoryData } = this.state;
    return(
      <div key={key} >
        {this.createCell(spotHistoryData, columnIndex, rowIndex, style)}
      </div>
    );
  }


  createCell(items, columnIndex, rowIndex, style){
    const formattedTimestamp = (new Date(items[rowIndex].time_stamp_decision)).toLocaleString();
    const btnColor = 'white';
    switch(columnIndex){
      case 0:
        return this.renderHistoryImageButton(
                  this.createCellId(columnIndex, rowIndex), 
                  btnColor, 
                  style, 
                  formattedTimestamp, 
                  items[rowIndex].image_decision
                );
      case 1:
        return this.renderHistoryDataButton(
                  this.createCellId(columnIndex, rowIndex), 
                  btnColor, 
                  style, 
                  'Timestamp', 
                  formattedTimestamp
                );
      ...
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { height, rowHeight } = this.props;
    const { width, spotHistoryData } = this.state;

    return(
      <Col>
        <Grid 
          width={width}
          height={height}
          rowHeight={rowHeight}
          cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
          rowCount={spotHistoryData.length} 
          columnCount={7}
          columnWidth={this.getCellWidth}
          estimatedColumnSize={100}
          overscanRowCount={3} 
          overscanColumnCount={3}
          onSectionRendered={this.whenSectionRendered}
          noContentRenderer={this.renderNoContent}
        />
      </Col>
    );
  }
}
```

My expectations are that once the promise returns that provides the image data and updates the state of the "spotHistoryData" object, the images attached to the objects would be displayed without any scroll action being required.